# upstream connect error or disconnect/reset before headers in envoy proxy

Tags: oauth-2.0, oauth, google-oauth, envoyproxy

I am trying to deploy an envoy proxy in a cloud run service which will act as an authentication gateway and do the token exchange with identity provider. Once it successfully authenticated it will always redirect to another cloud run service. But the following configuration giving the **upstream connect error or disconnect/reset before headers. reset reason: connection termination**  error after successful authentication. When I hit the https://envoy-proxy.cloud.run.app url then it going to the Google authentication page after providing credentials it should go the next cloud run service https://hello-world-ey.run.app

Any help would be appreciated .

```
static_resources:
  listeners:
  - name: listener_proxy
    address:
      socket_address:
        address: 0.0.0.0
        port_value: 8080
    filter_chains:
    - filters:
      - name: envoy.filters.network.http_connection_manager
        typed_config:
          "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.network.http_connection_manager.v3.HttpConnectionManager
          codec_type: auto
          stat_prefix: ingress_http
          route_config:
            name: local_route
            virtual_hosts:
            - name: upstream
              domains:
              - "*"
              routes:
              - match:
                  prefix: /
                redirect: { https_redirect: true }
                route:
                  cluster: upstream-service
          http_filters:
          - name: envoy.filters.http.oauth2
            typed_config:
              "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.http.oauth2.v3.OAuth2
              config:
                token_endpoint:
                  cluster: google-oauth2-token
                  uri: https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token
                  timeout: 3s
                authorization_endpoint: https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth
                redirect_uri: https://envoy-proxy.cloud.run.app/callback
                signout_path:
                  path:
                    exact: /oauth2/signout
                credentials:
                  client_id: "**********"
                  token_secret:
                    name: token
                    sds_config:
                      path: "/etc/envoy/token-secret.yaml"
                  hmac_secret:
                    name: hmac
                    sds_config:
                      path: "/etc/envoy/hmac-secret.yaml"
                forward_bearer_token: true
                auth_scopes:
                  - openid
          - name: envoy.filters.http.router
            typed_config:
             "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.http.router.v3.Router
  clusters:
  - name: google-oauth2-token
    connect_timeout: 0.487s
    type: LOGICAL_DNS
    dns_lookup_family: V4_ONLY
    lb_policy: ROUND_ROBIN
    load_assignment:
      cluster_name: google-oauth2-token
      endpoints:
      - lb_endpoints:
        - endpoint:
            address:
              socket_address:
                address: oauth2.googleapis.com
                port_value: 443
    transport_socket:
      name: envoy.transport_sockets.tls
      typed_config:
        "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.transport_sockets.tls.v3.UpstreamTlsContext
        sni: oauth2.googleapis.com
  - name: upstream-service
    connect_timeout: 10s
    type: STRICT_DNS
    lb_policy: ROUND_ROBIN
    load_assignment:
      cluster_name: upstream-service
      endpoints:
      - lb_endpoints:
        - endpoint:
            address:
              socket_address:
                address: hello-world-ey.run.app
                port_value: 443
```